# Jquery change image on hover when image and menu item 'title' equal eachother

Tags: jquery, title, conditional-statements

This is now solved. I simplified the code.

My problem now is that whenever I hover over all list items (shown below ul.menu) then hover over again, upon inspection **style="display:none;"** is not being removed after I come back to mouseover again.

Current Html:

```
<ul class="menu">
 <li class="menu-mlid-187" id="ElDorado"><a title="El Dorado" href="/el-dorado">El Dorado</a></li>
 <li class="menu-mlid-202" id="TheGrand"><a title="The Grand" href="/grand">The Grand</a></li>
</ul>
```

The images that need to change when each menu item is moused over:

```
<div id="bannerContainer">

  <div class="view-content">

   <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">     
        <span class="field-content">

             <a href="/el-dorado" class="imagefield imagefield-nodelink imagefield-field_image">
<img  class="imagefield imagefield-field_image equal" width="636" height="420" alt="" title="El Dorado" src="http://localhost:8888/sites/default/files/eldoradobanner.jpg" />
             </a>

       </span>
      </div>
     </div>

    <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even views-row-last">       
         <span class="field-content">

             <a href="/grand" class="imagefield imagefield-nodelink imagefield-field_image">
<img  class="imagefield imagefield-field_image equal" width="636" height="420" alt="" title="The Grand" src="http://localhost:8888/sites/default/files/grandbanner.jpg" />
             </a>

       </span>
    </div>   

  </div>
<!-- default image -->
  <div id="upload">
   <img width="636" height="561" title='venues' src="http://localhost:8888/sites/default/files/venues_banner.jpg" alt="" class="imagefield imagefield-field_image">                     
</div>

</div>
```

Updated Jquery

```
// Dynamic mouse over menu item to display image utilizing titles
     $('#content .menu-block-3 ul.menu a').mouseover( function(){
         $("#bannerContainer #upload").fadeOut('fast'); 
        var sharedtitle = $(this).attr("title");        
        $('#bannerContainer img[title = "'+sharedtitle+'" ]').fadeIn('fast');   
    });
     $('#content .menu-block-3 ul.menu a').mouseout( function(){
         $("#bannerContainer #upload").fadeIn('fast'); 
        var sharedtitle = $(this).attr("title");
        $('#bannerContainer img[title = "'+sharedtitle+'" ]').fadeOut('fast');
    });
```

CSS:

```
/****** Venues Rollover navigation menu ******/
.view-ImageRollover {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    top: 0;
}
.view-ImageRollover .view-content {  /* outer container */
    position: relative;
}
.view-ImageRollover .field-content img {  /* inner container */
    display: block!Important;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px;
}
/* default image */
#upload {
    float: left;
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
}
#upload .imagefield-field_image img{
    left:0px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[You can see dev site here](http://cvs.pcanewmedia.com/venues).

Does anyone have an idea of what my issue is? let me know if im not clear. I tried adding display:block to the .imagefield but it gets over wridden by the jquery and won't go back to block.

Comment: The ID is `/grand`, with that slash in there?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What should change on what mouseover?

Comment: when I mouseover The Grand or El Dorado, I want field-content to changes images. I should of said there is an image for each anchor that needs to appear.   field-content contains 1 more image with parent div of el-dorado

Comment: Can anyone please help. I think i need to pass a variable to a function which then allows me to add css. Am i correct, if so please describe how in code. thanks...

Comment: UI am not 100% sure what behavior you are trying to change. Here is the behavior I am seeing: When page loads, 1) I see the default image. (let's call this default.gif) 2) When I mouse over the "El Dorado" text I see a new banner: (let's call this ElDorado.gif) 3) When I mouse Off the "El Dorado" text , default.gif replaces ElDorado.gif. Is the last part the issue? do you want ElDorado.gif to stay as the active image wn the mouse out occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot

note that Jquery allows you to locate element values using the following syntax: 
IMG[title='somevalue']

```
<html>
<head>
<script  src='jquery.min.js' ></script>


<script type="text/javascript"> 

 $(document).ready(function() { 

    $('ul.menu a').mouseover( function(){
        var sharedtitle = $(this).attr("title");
        $('#bannerContainer img[title = "'+sharedtitle+'" ]').addClass('equal');         
    });


    $('ul.menu a').mouseout( function(){
        var sharedtitle = $(this).attr("title");
        $('#bannerContainer img[title = "'+sharedtitle+'" ]').removeClass('equal');     });


}); 


</script>
</Head>
<body>


<ul class="menu"> 
 <li class="menu-mlid-187" id="ElDorado"><a title="El Dorado" href="/el-dorado">El Dorado</a></li> 
 <li class="menu-mlid-202" id="TheGrand"><a title="The Grand" href="/grand">The Grand</a></li> 
</ul> 


<div id="bannerContainer"> 

  <div class="view-content"> 

   <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">      
        <span class="field-content"> 

             <a href="/el-dorado" class="imagefield imagefield-nodelink imagefield-field_image"> 
<img  class="imagefield imagefield-field_image equal" width="636" height="420" alt="" title="El Dorado" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo14.png" /> 
             </a> 

       </span> 
      </div> 
     </div> 

    <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even views-row-last">        
         <span class="field-content"> 

             <a href="/grand" class="imagefield imagefield-nodelink imagefield-field_image"> 
<img  class="imagefield imagefield-field_image equal" width="636" height="420" alt="" title="The Grand" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo14.png" /> 
             </a> 

       </span> 
    </div>    

  </div> 
<!-- default image --> 
  <div id="upload"> 
   <img width="636" height="561" title='venues' src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo14.png" alt="" class="imagefield imagefield-field_image">                      
</div> 

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh thank you! you are a live saver! I was almost on the right track but you hit spot on. thanks brian!

Comment: Unfortunately, I have encountered an issue when I mouse over all elements, then come back to see them again. upon inspection, jquery adds display:none right after I mouse out. I would like it to toggle that display: none after I cycle through the li

Comment: Are you using the code as posted or a variation? If you made changes, Please post the code you are using.[edit the original question] (The code in my response does nothing with the display Property).

Comment: strange problem i encountered.  It seems it working on the dev server but on my local (mamp) it behaves as i stated above.

Comment: Please post all as you have it on you machine. The location/wenserver should not matter.