# Jquery Toggle to change image if .text() equal img[title]

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

With help from the community last week, I successfully implemented this [code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515914/jquery-change-image-on-hover-when-image-and-menu-item-title-equal-eachother)

Now i need to do something similar but now compare html text with [title]. My code so far is below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".views-field-field-success-stories-image-data .field-content").click(function() {
   var sharedata = $(this).text();
   $('#bannerContainer img[title = "'+sharedata+'" ]').addClass('selected');
 });
 $("#bannerContainer img").click(function() {
  if (
   $('#bannerContainer img').hasClass('selected', $('#bannerContainer img').removeClass('selected') ) );

 });
});


      <span class="field-content">The Grand Event Center</span>
      <span class="field-content">Choura Events Catering</span>
      <span class="field-content">El Dorado Park Golf Course</span>

<div id="bannerContainer">
 <img src="1.jpg" title="The Grand Event Center" class="selected">
 <img src="1.jpg" title="The Grand Event Center" class="selected"> 
 <img src="1.jpg" title="The Grand Event Center" class="selected">
</div>

<!--- My Goal
<div id="bannerContainer">
 <img src="1.jpg" title="The Grand Event Center" class="">
 <img src="1.jpg" title="The Grand Event Center" class=""> 
 <img src="1.jpg" title="The Grand Event Center" class="selected">
</div> ---->
```

I am having trouble wrapping my head around toggleClass for some reason.

Currently, if i click on any one of the spans, the 'selected' sticks and doesnt leave when i click on any another span.

What am I missing?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually accomplish this by just removing the class from all the related elements right before I add the class to the current element (the one you just selected).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".views-field-field-success-stories-image-data .field-content").click(function() {

   // Add this next line
   $("#bannerContainer img").removeClass("selected");

   var sharedata = $(this).text();
   $('#bannerContainer img[title = "'+sharedata+'" ]').addClass('selected');
 });
 $("#bannerContainer img").click(function() {
  if (
   $('#bannerContainer img').hasClass('selected', $('#bannerContainer     img').removeClass('selected') ) );
 });
});
```

Comment: Perfecto! This might be a whole other question but I keep running into the problem when I want to use z-index in order change images, IE 6 and 7 don't read it. any hints?

thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, it's a whole other question. - If my answer works for you, you should mark it as the accepted answer by pressing the check mark to the left.

Answer (score 0):

how about removing the 'selected' class from all elements that have it, before setting it again on the one element?